# nginx as load balancer with redirection to internal servers

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx configuration that has the task of receiving calls on a server for a
rest service and redirecting them, balancing them between two servers.
However, the following configuration does not work in a production environment
and I get a 400 error

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.1.36:8085;
    server 192.168.1.38:8085;
}
#
server {
    listen 8085 ssl;
    server_name 10.10.10.10;
    ssl_certificate /home/user/mydomain.cer;    
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/mydomain.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

The configuration below works in a test environment

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.1.36:8085;
    server 192.168.1.38:8085;
}
#
server {
    listen 8085 ssl;
    server_name 192.168.1.30;
    ssl_certificate /home/user/mydomain.cer;    
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/mydomain.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

I understood that the problem is due to the different class of IPs. How can I fix?
Any help is appreciated. Thank

Comment: Please share the nginx `access.log`.

Comment: If you enable `events { debug_connection your_browser_IP; }` and then set the `error_log` level to `info` you should be able to see what happens and it does not work.